# good reference for kernel density estimation.

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, probability-distributions

Please suggest a good reference for an introduction to Kernel Density Estimation. I am an electrical engineer, and I want some basic introduction so that I can start using it and also understand its working. I have basic knowledge of probability and random variables as taught in engineering courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David W. Scott, ***Multivariate Density Estimation***.

Bernard. W. Silverman, ***Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis***.